# How to start Firebug's performance profiler at page load?

Tags: javascript, performance, profiling, firebug

So, Firebug has a JavaScript performance profiler that I never managed to notice before…

[image: pic of the Firebug profiler button]

Now I'd like to use it to troubleshoot page load performance issues, but I can't quite hit the button quick enough! Surely there's a way to profile a page from the very start of execution?

Comment: ...I can do this easily using the built-in Web developer tools, but in FireBug, reloading the page stops the profiling session.

Answer (score 8):

[Firebug wiki](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console.profile) says you can do this with simple javascript `console.profile`
So in your html page you can do it like this:

```
console.profile("Your new profiler");
alert('Open firebug profiles tab to see result');    
console.profileEnd();
```

Comment: ...looks promising. I'll give it a go in a bit... Thanks.